# DialogFlow sending context back after authentication?

Tags: javascript, api, bots, dialogflow-es

I am having a bit of a hard time wrapping my head around how to connect to my OAuth2 Freshbooks API from my bot. Currently I have my API set up such that hitting the /auth route will take the user to the Freshbooks login page and once successfully authenticated the token is returned back to the user. After we have the token the user can get all of their invoices in my web app.

Now, when I build a DialogFlow bot, how do I go about this? What I have thought about is that the user first hits the /auth route which returns the authorization URL which the user can then open in their browser and log in...but after login, how do I return back to my bot?

After a successful login, the /callback route is called by my api with the authorization code to get the token...but this will not be returned back to the bot since it is all happening in the browser...I think.

What is the best approach for this?

Also, after getting the token from my API, should this be stored in a context in my bot?

Thanks for the help and sorry if this is a beginner question. I tried finding an answer online but I just cant wrap my head around this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your OAuth service is configured correctly you don't have to worry about any of this. The procedure works roughly as follows:

- Account linking is triggered via one of two ways:

  - If you need a linked account to fulfill a certain intent you can simply check the `Sign in required` box of that intent in the Google Assistant integrations page in your Dialogflow project. If you check this for all intents that are listed for invocation the user can only use your agent once they have an account linked.
  - The other option is to manually call the [`sigin helper`](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#request_the_signin_helper). This can be done at any point during the conversation, i.e. it does not have to be tied to a particular intent.
- When the account linking procedure starts the Google Assistant will load your login page in an in-app browser.
- Once the user has authorized your client the OAuth service should (like any OAuth service) redirect the user back to the client. On the Google Assistant this happens via a redirect url of the format `https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/<google developer project ID>`.
- After that Actions on Google calls your fulfillment service with the original intent (the one that triggered account linking), only this time with a valid access token for your service.
- Such an access token will from now on be included in every fulfillment request your receive from Actions on Google. You do not have to store this token, you should always use the one that is send in the request.

For more details see the [Implement Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try this approach when I get home today but I do have one question, perhaps related to my lack of knowledge about the Google Assistant. Right now I am doing everything in the DialogFlow GUI so that once the user calls the authorization API, the link for authorization is returned to the user, they click that link and a sign in page opens. After they sign in, they see a successful page but it does not redirect to the FB messenger chat. Do I enter the redirect URL in the DialogFlow GUI or Google Assistant. I guess I'm confused where Google Assistant comes in?

Comment: This is indeed somewhat confusing, while you are normally developing your agent on Dialogflow account linking is one of the features that has to be configured in your Actions on Google project. The URL for that would be something like `https://console.actions.google.com/u/2/project/YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE/accountlinking/`. See [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/dialogflow-actions-on-google) for a more detailed explanation of how Dialogflow and AoG relate. (Note that your users do not have to click a link manually, the login page loads automatically, as does the redirect URL.)

Comment: Thanks again for your help, it is making more sense now but I'm still a bit stuck. I have created my action and added myself as an alpha tester. I can now access the app in google assistant on my phone and I can click 'LINK'. It opens the Freshbooks (third party api) login page, I log in and then I am returned back to the Google Assistant. Continued in the next comment...

Comment: But my DialogFlow agent still has no idea of this action, I added the integration to the Default Welcome Intent and made it sign in required, however, when I say hi to my agent the login to Freshbooks is not opened. I tried adding the Google Assistant Welcome Event but that still does nothing. Am I missing something? My end goal is to have a Facebook Messenger bot where I can tell it to log time to Freshbooks but before logging time I need to link it to my account - this seems to be the hardest part :(.

Comment: It seems that the Facebook Messenger integration doesn't have the option to mark individual intents with sign in required. You could try to trigger the signin helper manually (see my original answer), but googling around it seems not entirely clear if the FB integration does support account linking at all. I think you would really have to try it with the signin helper (and maybe post the results to one of the open questions:)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up submitting a support ticket to DialogFlow team and turns out account linking with third party APIs is no yet supported in DialogFlow but is supported in actions on Google. I'll have to try doing the linking myself and redirecting to my FB messenger bot outside of DialogFlow. In either case, thank you for your help!